# How to create a polygon dynamically on google map using jsf with derby database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

How to create a polygon dynamically on google map using jsf with derby database?This code worked for static points but i have dynamic data in  points entity. How to get those points and display in google map?

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <style>
          #map {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 1000px;
          }
        </style>
        <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
        <script>
         function initialize() {


          var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 5,
          center: {lat: 17.68, lng: 83.21},
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        });

      // Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's path.
       var triangleCoords = [
         {lat: 18.3000, lng: 83.900},
         {lat: 18.1713, lng:  82.1278},
         {lat: 17.370, lng: 78.480},
         {lat: 17.68, lng: 83.21},
       ];

      // Construct the polygon.
        var bermudaTriangle = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: triangleCoords,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: '#FF0000',
        fillOpacity: 0.35

      });
      bermudaTriangle.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well you'll need to use a server-side language to query your database. I don't know anything about Ofbiz or Derby, but Google's documentation provides [an example using PHP and MySQL](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should download gmaps4jsf jar file and use it. GMaps4JSF integrating Google maps with JSF. you can create java beans class and call the value dynamically through JSF. You can refer this http://www.mashups4jsf.com/gmaps4jsf-examples2-3.0.0/pages/welcome.xhtml it will help you.
or Here I am giving one example.

**JSF code:**

```
 <m:map id="map" width="1080px" height="350px" partiallyTriggered="true" latitude="#{pointBean.mapLatitude}" longitude="#{pointBean.mapLongitude}" enableScrollWheelZoom="true">
                    <m:polygon id="polygon" lineWidth="2" hexStrokeColor="red" hexFillColor="lightpink">
                        <ui:repeat var="point" value="#{pointBean.points}" varStatus="status" offset="0" step="1" size="#{pointBean.points.size()}">
                            <m:point latitude="#{point.latitude.toString()}" longitude="#{point.longitude.toString()}">
                            </m:point>
                        </ui:repeat>
                    </m:polygon>
                </m:map>
```

**pointBean class:**(java bean class)

```
private List<Point> points;
private Float mapLatitude;
private Float mapLongitude;//create getter or setter also

public List<Point> getlatlong() {

        String query = ".....";//write here your query
        points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        Point point = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            connection = ConnectionFactory.getConnection();//here is connection for jdbc connectivity
            statement = connection.createStatement();
            rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                point = new Point();
                point.setLatitude(rs.getFloat("latitude"));
                point.setLongitude(rs.getFloat("longitude"));
                points.add(point);
            }
            mapLatitude = points.get(0).getLatitude();
             mapLongitude = points.get(0).getLongitude();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            DBUtil.close(rs);
            DBUtil.close(statement);
            DBUtil.close(connection);
        }
           return points;
       }
public List<Point> getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10384386)

Comment: @StefanGehrig, I edited my answer. i tried this example and getting dynamic polygon on google map using gmaps4jsf jar.